# Submitting form with content-header application/x-www-form-urlencoded gets 404 error but is working fine in Postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, post

I'm building a login page with React handling the front end and Express, the back end. When I click submit, it returns with the error in the console:

POST http://localhost:8000/auth/login 404 (Not Found)

But when I use postman instead to test out posting to /auth/login it is successful. In the processForm function, I've tried fetching a different api with post that I have written just to see if it's a front end issue and it comes back with 422 error (as expected) so I'm guessing it's a backend problem but I'm not sure what the problem is.

This is the function in a react component I'm using to process the form:

```
  processForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const email = encodeURIComponent(this.state.user.email);
    const password = encodeURIComponent(this.state.user.password);
    const formData = `email=${email}&password=${password}`;

    fetch('/auth/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      body: formData
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then(() => {
          this.setState({
            errors: {}
          });
          console.log('The form is valid');
        })
      } else {
        response.json().then(error => {
          const errors = error ? error : {};
          errors.message = error.message;
          this.setState({
            errors
          });
        });
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

And how I'm handling the back end with express router:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const validationResult = validateLoginForm(req.body);
  if (!validationResult.success) {
    res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      message: validationResult.message,
      errors: validationResult.errors,
    });
  }
  res.status(200).end();
});
```

and the relevant code for mounting the route in server.js:

```
import AuthRoutes from './routes/auth';

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/auth', AuthRoutes);
```

Comment: You're not using any middleware that may be causing the 404?

Comment: Try a different browser (Firefox, Chrome, Safari). Sometimes security extensions or the browser itself prevents posting username and password type data over an unencrypted connection. If you look in the Chrome inspector and is says "provisional headers shown" that means the post was blocked by the client before it ever left your machine.

Comment: @GardnerBickford I'm using Chrome. Would the message "provisional headers shown" be in the console? It's not there

Comment: In Chrome it would be in the network tab of the developer tools. 

See this [screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/TuUvT9d.png)